# combining rows in python which follows some condition

Tags: python

I have some list as:

```
a=['abc','123','def','ghi','456','jkl','789','mno','pqr']
```

I want to combine the elements of list if the element is number,i.e it contains 0-9
like:

```
b=['abc 123','def','ghi 456','jkl 789','mno','pqr']
```

How to do it? I have a solution if the numeric elements are given as number(like `int`) but here they are stings.Please help

Suppose if `a=['abc',123,'def','ghi',456,'jkl',789,'mno','pqr']`
then we can do:

```
t=[]
for i in a:
    if isinstance(i, int):
        t[-1] = "{0} {1}".format(t[-1], i)
    else:
        t.append(i)
print(t)
```

then output will be :

```
t=['abc 123','def','ghi 456','jkl 789','mno','pqr']
```

How to do it for `a=['abc','123','def','ghi','456','jkl','789','mno','pqr']`

Note:If the first element is a number then it should it should stay as it is.
Also I have such a list that no two numeric elements comes in continuous rows.

Comment: please make an attempt before asking, SO is not a coding service

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: "I have a solution if the numeric elements are given as number(like int) but here they are strings." that implies that the only question you need to ask is how to recognise a string that contains only numbers, and you've already figured out the combining elements of a list part. Is that right? If not, show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=['abc','123','def','ghi','456','jkl','789','mno','pqr']

new_lst = []
for x in a:
    if x.isdigit():
        new_lst[-1] += ' {}'.format(x)
    else:
        new_lst.append(x)
print(new_lst)
```

**Output**

```
['abc 123', 'def', 'ghi 456', 'jkl 789', 'mno', 'pqr']
```